is there a current version of Brahmanda Purana that includes the so-called "Ahobila Mahatmyam"?
It is claimed that a scripture called "Ahobala mahatmyam" exists as part of Brahmanda Purana.
https://ia600403.us.archive.org/3/items/shri-ahobila-narasimha-mahatmyam-brahmanda-puranam-english/Shri%20Ahobila-Mahatmyam%20%28Brahmanda-Puranam%29%20Pandit%20Dr.%20V.%20Krishnamachariyar%20%28ENG%20by%20S.%20Shreyas%29.pdf
Its claim to fame is a Vaishnavite "postscript" to the Sharabha-Narasimha saga in which Vishnu emerges victorious.
Jagadguru Shrimat Vijayeendra Teertha Shripaada in his
https://ia802709.us.archive.org/13/items/shaiva-sarvasva-khandanam/ShaivaSarvasvaKhandanam.pdf#:~:text=This%20section%20of%20Nyaayamauktikamaala%20deals%20with
doesn't include the version from "Ahobila Mahatmyam" when he lists proofs (all unattested) for the Vaishnavite version of the Narasimha-Sharabha fight.  This suggests "Ahobila mahatmyam" didn't exist in Jagadguru Shrimat Vijayeendra Teertha Shripaada's time (16th century)

The Puranas available in print aren't necessarily the only version. The printed versions are thes one published by the Venkateshwara Press of Mumbai in the 19th century. Outside those versions, multiple recessions & extensions exist for the same text, confined in manuscripts, but the authenticity of those versions are considered to be doubtful. But that doesn't means that they are forgeries. For example, Vedanta Desika had quoted lines from the Maghamasamahatmya of Padma Purana in his Rahasyatrayasamgraha, but this text isn't included in the present printed version of Padma Purana.
